# function in a hrefnot working using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have redirect function which needs to be run on click event.
when i click in this `<li>` nothing happens.
my code :

```
<li class="list-group-item" title="<?php echo $rows['title']; ?>" >
    <a href="javascript:redirect(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
         <span class="badge pull-right bg-primary "><?php echo $rowp['nbr']; ?>
         </span><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>&nbsp;
          <?php echo $name; ?>
    </a>
</li>

<script>
    function redirect(val){
        document.getElementById("che").value=val;
        document.forms["f2"].submit();
    }
</script>
<form name="f2" action="session.php" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" id="che" name="id">
</form>
```

Comment: any errors in your browser console? Did you use the debugger? "Nothing happens" isn't a very useful description of your problem

Comment: that's not a function that runs on click. It's a function that SHOULD return a href value. Your function does not return anything. use `onclick=function.....` on the `a` element.

Comment: in my console i get this erroe : Uncaught ReferenceError: redirect is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Answer (score -1):

That's not a function that runs on click.

It's a function that looks like it SHOULD return a href value and runs on page load.
Your function does not return anything.

If you want the function to run on `click` on `a`, use `onlick` handler.

See below

```js
  function redirect(val){
        document.getElementById("che").value=val;
        // document.forms["f2"].submit();
    }
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item" >
    <a onclick="javascript:redirect('valueOnInput')">
       <span>Click me</span>
    </a>
</li>
<form name="f2" action="session.php" method="post" >
    <input id="che" name="id">
</form>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:redirect(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">

this is a valid usage for calling JS function

@Chinigami   you should check in your console if there is any issue, most probably it should be issue in your data coming from $row

Comment: @A_J in my console i get this erroe : Uncaught ReferenceError: redirect is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: no need to down vote a perfectly working answer. Just be sure your script is loaded. Maybe wrap it inside a window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {. If the code snippet in the answer works it means that the problem is on your side.